# With Apache Superset installed from a git clone - How to download the assets when installed from scratch?

Tags: apache-superset

I have superset installed from a git clone.

All seems to be working ok but I don't have the assets. For example "/static/assets/images/superset-logo-horiz.png" is missing.

I have been looking around the official documentation but I cannot how.

Comment: it will be fetched from docker build i think, run `docker-compose build` &
`docker-compose up`

Comment: No. As I said I installed it from scratch. No docker. But maybe you can point me to the Docker line that fetch it?